# MySQL select every day last row orderered by date DESC

Tags: mysql

i have data,

```
Stamp                dataField1 dataFiel2
2012-05-23 23:59:59  ....        ....
2012-05-23 23:50:00  ....        ....
2012-05-24 24:43:23  ....        ....
2012-05-24 24:12:10  ....        ....
2012-05-25 25:15:00  ....        ....
2012-05-26 25:53:59  ....        ....
```

and i want to select every day last row and result should look li

```
Stamp                dataField1 dataFiel2
2012-05-23 23:59:59  ....        ....
2012-05-24 24:43:23  ....        ....
2012-05-26 25:53:59  ....        ....
```

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Is there an ID column in that table?

Comment: What is the data type of the column `Stamp`? If it is a datetime, how it can be a time like `24:43:23` or `25:53:59`?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal : I believe OP was putting raw data and missed that... from 23 he increased time by 1... so it is 23...24...25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT MAX(Stamp) as Stamp, dataField1, dataField2
FROM tableName
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(Stamp)
```

**I would say use** ***`DAYOFYEAR`***  **instead of** ***`DAY`***  **as everyone stated. For difference, see below link.**

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d485/2)

In this demo, `DAY` gives 3 rows which is ***INCORRECT*** as oppose to 4 rows using `DAYOFYEAR`.

Comment: dataField1 and dataField2 can be from arbitrary rows in each day, not necessarily the last row of each day.

Comment: @Barmar : I don't get what you want to say...

Comment: This answer is incorrect as dataField1, dataField2 would be random values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Stamp) as Last, other_column FROM table GROUP BY DAY(Stamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Stamp, dataField1, dataFiel2  FROM tableName 
GROUP BY Stamp ORDER BY Stamp ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  Stamp, dataField1, dataField2, dataField3
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Stamp DESC) t
GROUP BY
  DATE(Stamp)
```